# How to create a HTML based layout GUI application in Python?

Tags: python, html, windows, user-interface, layout

I'm on the search to create a standalone HTML layout based GUI application with CSS/JavaScript support in Python, which I could compile to a EXE file later.

I already tried that with the html2 module of the [wxPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPython) library. Unfortunately there was no way to bind Python functions to the HTML buttons or links.

The next I tried was using the [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) module of the [PyQt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt) library where I got more features and an option to bind those buttons (just in old tutorials). But I wasn't conviced of the render quality in opposite to the html2 module.

The result should look like a Windows 8 [Metro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29) application ;)

My operation system is Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: What do you mean by "render quality"?

Comment: I mean the text is a bit blurry it looks like on linux not like defaultly on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you check out [Tide](http://www.tidesdk.org/). I have just finished building an application with it and I'm pretty happy. It's still in beta, but that is fine... I didn't come across any issues.

Comment: the tide seems to be out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Flask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) or [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) for server side and use a framework like [Jinja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinja_%28template_engine%29) 2 and JavaScript ([Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)) for client-server commumication.